# Need a boolean result by finding whether 2 elements are present in an array or not

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects:

```
quesListArray = [
                  {
                    QuestionTypeID : 1,
                    QuestionTypeName : 'Rating'
                  },
                  {
                    QuestionTypeID : 2,
                    QuestionTypeName : 'Yes/No'
                  },
                  {
                    QuestionTypeID : 3,
                    QuestionTypeName : 'Rating - Matrix'
                  },
                  {
                    QuestionTypeID : 4,
                    QuestionTypeName : 'Yes/No - Matrix'
                  }
                ]
```

I want a boolean result for if QuestionTypeID 1 & 3 are present in the array, then return true, else false. Similarly with 2 & 4. Also if any other combination of ID's present, it should return false.

I tried to use for loop:

```
for(let x of this.quesListArray) {
  if(x.QuestionTypeID == 1 && x.QuestionTypeID == 3) {   // realised it's incorrect condition
     // return true or false
  }
}
```

Then I used includes() as:

```
this.quesListArray.includes(this.QuesListArray[..])  // Was not sure that what to write so as to get both ID's condition.
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.find` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
if (
     quesListArray.find(x=>x.QuestionTypeID == 1) && 
     && quesListArray.find(x=>x.QuestionTypeID == 3)
) {
  // It has both 1 and 3 in there.
}
```

Comment: You can optimize this in one find loop as `if ( quesListArray.find(x => { return  x.QuestionTypeID == 1 &&  x.QuestionTypeID == 3 } )  )`

Comment: `QuestionTypeID` cannot be `1` and `3` simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using includes and find as following

let assume first you have pair p1

```
let p1 = [1,3];
```

then your first find condition will be

```
let result = quesListArray.filter(q => p1.includes(q.QuestionTypeID)).length == 2;
```

this will give result as boolean true/false result based on quesListArray contains two elements that have QuestionTypeID as 1 and 3, if not either one is present then it will be result in false.

Comment: Does not cater for all cases e.g. this will pass even if only `1` is found and no `3` exists in `quesListArray`

Comment: Edited my answer by improving it for checking that it quesListArray must have two elements that can have QuestionTypeID as either 1 or 3,

it can be more dynamic if we compare `filter().length == p1.length`